# Finding date with regex in strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I was trying to create a function that will verify if there is a valid date (YYYY-MM-DD) inside a string and then return it as a result of the function.

So far I have this:

```
function findDate(str){
   let dateReg = /^(19[7-9]\d|20[0-1][0-7])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/([0-2][1-9]|3[0-1])$/;
   let matchingDate = [];
   let strSplit = str.split(' ');

    for(let i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++){
      if(dateReg.test(strSplit[i])){
        matchingDate.push(strSplit[i]);
      } else {
        return 'No valid date';
      }
    }

    return matchingDate;

}

findDate('I was born on 2017/12/05 ok?');
// findDate('She was born on 1960/08/31 ok?');
// findDate('He was born on 2010/15/31 ok?');
```

Any idea what am I missing? By default it skips the test part.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you site an example on how to use match on this case?

Comment: function findDate(str){
  let dateReg = /(19[7-9]\d|20[0-1][0-7])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/([0-2][1-9]|3[0-1])/;
  return str.match(dateReg)[0];
}

Comment: function findDate(str){
  let dateReg = /(19[7-9]\d|20[0-1][0-7])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/([0-2][1-9]|3[0-1])/;
  return str.match(dateReg) ? str.match(dateReg)[0] : 'No valid date';
}

findDate('I was born on 2017/12/05 ok?');
findDate('She was born on 1960/08/31 ok?');

Comment: WOOOOOW! Awesome oneliner solution. haha.

Comment: +10 for the short answer. haha.

Comment: @nnnnn: Yeah. This is just for testing regex program. I am just practicing around.

Comment: I've deleted my comments and posted it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you immediately return the function whenever it encounter a string that's not a valid date (based on your regex). Try this one

```js
function findDate(str){
   let dateReg = /^(19[7-9]\d|20[0-1][0-7])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/([0-2][1-9]|3[0-1])$/;
   let matchingDate = [];
   let strSplit = str.split(' ');

   for(let i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++){
     if(dateReg.test(strSplit[i])){
        matchingDate.push(strSplit[i]);
     } 
   }
   return matchingDate.length == 0 ? 'No valid date' : matchingDate;

}

findDate('I was born on 2017/12/05 ok?');
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [Pratansyah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47425875/615754), your current code returns from the function as soon as any one word doesn't match the regex.

But note that you don't need to split the string and test the words individually, you can use the [string `.match()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to search the whole string, substantially shrinking your function:

```js
function findDate(str){
   let dateReg = /\b(19[7-9]\d|20[0-1][0-7])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/([0-2][1-9]|3[0-1])\b/g;
   return str.match(dateReg) || 'No valid date';
}

console.log(findDate('I was born on 2017/12/05 ok?'));
console.log(findDate('She was born on 1960/08/31 ok?')); // doesn't match
console.log(findDate('He was born on 2010/15/31 ok?'));  // doesn't match
console.log(findDate('He was born 2010/12/31, and she was born 2011/11/02, ok?'));
```

Note that for use with `.match()` like this the regex should *not* have `^` and `$` or it will only match if the string contains just a date, but you probably want `\b` instead to match word boundaries. If you add the `g` flag to the regex it will find all matching dates within the string.

If there are no matches then `.match()` returns `null`, so I've used the `||` operator to default to the `'No valid date'` message for those cases.

(And note that this isn't actually validating the dates because it assumes all months can have 31 days so it would accept 2017/02/31.)